Wireframe weight paint?
I'm looking to increase certain weights on an object with the wireframe modifier look - and can't seem to find any tutorials online regarding this specific look. I'm sure this is a simple goal but finding to see if anyone has any suggestions that I've overlooked? This is an experimental piece and just looking to gain more experience through Blender, please also drop any suggestions for interesting wireframe looks if there is!! Hope this all makes sense, thank you in advance!


Hello, what do you mean by "increase certain weights"?

Hi moonboots, sorry for the confusion. What I mean is that for example I want to see if its possible to animate the wireframe to increase thickness in certain areas

Instead of the Wireframe modifier you could use the Skin modifier, then use Ctrl A to thicken the vertices you want?

Does there happen to be another option besides utilizing the skin modifier? I experiment mostly on my laptop which is almost impossible to use the skin modifier without crashing
